# A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

[image]While integrating Jetpack Compose in existing Android Studio project, I'm getting error as mentioned. I have following setup:

```
kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
compose_version = '1.3.0'

buildFeatures {
   compose = true
}

composeOptions {
   kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
}
```

I have not added any compose dependencies. I expect code should build successfully. Can anyone help how to fix this?

I used kotlin_version and compose_version which are compatible. My compileSDK Version is 33.
I have not added any compose dependencies just to eliminate any possibility of errors due to dependencies.

Comment: Helo have you fixed this already?